# Identifying client IP from AWS ALB's X-Forwarded-For header while avoiding spoofing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, spoofing, x-forwarded-for

According to [AWS' documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for) on the ALB and the `X-Forwarded-For` header, the client IP is the left-most (so proxies would follow on the right):

> The left-most address is the client IP address where the request was first made.

However, if the user supplied their own `X-Fowarded-For` header, the client IP is appended to the provided header:

> the load balancer appends the client IP address to the existing header and passes the header to your server

If I understand the documentation correctly, the `X-Forwarded-For` header could look something like:
`spoofed,clientIp,proxy,proxy`

That would mean the actual client IP is somewhere between user-supplied values and proxies. We can't extract the left-most value because it may be spoofed (and even include a comma-separated value) and we can't extract the right-most value because it might be a proxy.

Is there a reliable way to identify the actual client IP?

Comment: If X-Forwarded-For is present in the request then "the load balancer appends the client IP address to the existing header and passes the header to your server." So, it will be the rightmost IP. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073092/prevent-x-forwarded-for-spoofing-using-elb-and-node).

Comment: If that's the case, it seems like the client IP is the leftmost if the header wasn't provided (see my first quote from the docs) but the rightmost if the header was provided. How would we distinguish between these two cases?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a reliable way to identify the actual client IP?

Not using `X-FORWARDED-FOR`. Not clear what you're using it for but this is from the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)

> The X-Forwarded-For header is untrustworthy when no trusted reverse
> proxy (e.g., a load balancer) is between the client and server. If the
> client and all proxies are benign and well-behaved, then the list of
> IP addresses in the header has the meaning described in the Directives
> section. But if there's a risk the client or any proxy is malicious or
> misconfigured, then it's possible any part (or the entirety) of the
> header may have been spoofed (and may not be a list or contain IP
> addresses at all).
>
> If any trusted reverse proxies are between the client and server, the
> final X-Forwarded-For IP addresses (one for each trusted proxy) are
> trustworthy, as they were added by trusted proxies. (That's true as
> long as the server is only accessible through those proxies and not
> also directly).
>
> Any security-related use of X-Forwarded-For (such as for rate limiting
> or IP-based access control) must only use IP addresses added by a
> trusted proxy. Using untrustworthy values can result in rate-limiter
> avoidance, access-control bypass, memory exhaustion, or other negative
> security or availability consequences.